# Arrange result from Iterate into Table JSP

Tags: loops, jsp, html-table, iteration

I have the DB query from database in class file:

```
List srActionList = hibernate_session.createQuery("from SrActionModal where srReportShow = 'Y' order by actDesc").list();

ArrayList dataResultList = new ArrayList();
SrActionModal status = new SrActionModal();

for (int i = 0; i < srActionList.size(); i++) {
    status = (SrActionModal) srActionList.get(i);
    status.setActDesc(status.getActDesc());
    dataResultList.add(status);
}
session.setAttribute("srActionList", dataResultList);
```

And I would like to show srActionList attribute into table. Currently my output just like below;

```
    <logic:iterate id="list" name="srActionList">
 <html:multibox property="selectedAction">
    <bean:write name="list" property='code'/>
 </html:multibox>
 <bean:write name="list" property='actDesc'/>
    </logic:iterate>
```

My question is, how to arrange the result into table for better arrangement? The limit column per row is 2. If the resultsize is 10, so there will be 5 rows that contain 2 column per row.

```
    <table>
     <tr> 
         <td>list 1</td> <td>list 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
         <td>list 3</td> <td>list 4</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the indexId attribute into a page context variable and test it for divisibility by 2; then insert a TR-tag on odd values and a end-TR-tag on even values.  Something like this:

```
   <table>
   <logic:iterate id="list" name="srActionList" indexId="index">
      <% Integer index = (Integer) pageContext.getAttribute("index");
      /* If not divisible by 2 then insert a table row marker */
      if (index.intValue() % 2 == 1) { %>
      <tr>
      <% } %>
      <td>
         <html:multibox property="selectedAction">
         <bean:write name="list" property='code'/>
            </html:multibox>
         <bean:write name="list" property='actDesc'/>
      </td>
      <% Integer index = (Integer) pageContext.getAttribute("index");
      /* If divisible by 2 then insert a table row end marker */
      if (index.intValue() % 2 == 0) { %>
      </tr>
      <% } %>
   </logic:iterate>
   </table>
```